# Is there any way we can do append on the next element？

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like, we have `<div id='target'></div><div id='footer'></div>`

i just want to append `<div id='target'></div>` , the result will be like

```
<div id='target'></div><div id='target'></div><div id='footer'></div>
```

append just append something inside the element,
 is there any Jquery method i can do this

Comment: your ID's need to be unique..!

Comment: you mean john? i just type some ramdon chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div#target").after($("div#target").clone());
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div />').after($('#target'))
```

IDs must be unique, otherwise you will have lots of problems with your selectors later on. The solution above will create a new `div` element and apend it after your `#target`

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('<div />').after('div#targetdiv')
```

Comment: This will append the div to the element not after it.